# How to type a nested object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to type an object to include it in a React state. This is a shopping cart object with a couple of product IDs and their props.

Object:

```
{
  "1047151242": {
      "name": "Item 1 name",
      "price": 22.99,
      "quantity": 2,
      "subtotal": 45.98
  },
  "3327300382": {
      "name": "Item 2 name",
      "price": 90.49,
      "quantity": 2,
      "subtotal": 180.98
  }
}
```

etc. where the product ID can be any string of the same format.

And then reference the type as such:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState<CartInterface>(CartState);
```

Comment: Did you read all of this? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html

Comment: I can type the cart item itself:

interface CartItem {
  name: string;
  price: number;
  quantity: number;
  subtotal: number;
};

What throws me off is the ID and how to formulate the interface to integrate it.

Yes I can read and I'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need a type

```js
type CartInterface = {
    [s: string]: {
        name: string;
        price: number;
        quantity: number;
        subtotal: number;
    }
}
```

Now when you use it like you mentioned, `cart` will be of type `CartInterface`.
If this answers your question, I suggest some deeper reading of the [typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html).
You can check this [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJ2ASQHbAggZnAxtAXigG8AoKCqAbQGkAuKAZ2AQEtUBzAXQbMv6io4AWwgNmbTuQEUwbfA1QBXYQCNM0mQEclcdK1CKV6hJoGMlq4AHtgcADZG1G-gF9S70rmupmUOAzwSGgY2HiEJNIARACMAAwALADsMQCsMQBMCRlRvGYUQqIMUcgYwlAxgiIQUQA0+VByrApQGRkAdACcnfXauvqGrb3mljZ2jlAJqV0AHNKuw1EAzEsZSUtxcUszOXkyhWJQJWWtVaJ1DU0tnXHtCT0NOnrABiAMGcP8Fla2DgwxM1unTmFHcriAA) to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks soffyo! 

I do read and I do study. What I couldn't figure out was the [s: string] bit.

Now that I saw your example I understand how it works.

Thanks for the pointer, much appreciated!